# Change order of x values in Excel (VBA)

Tags: excel, plot, graph

I am trying to make a plot of values collected on weekly basis over a period that stretches from one year to another. However, I can't figure out how to manipulate the order of the x-values of the plot when feeding the following values:

[Weekly data for category A and B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luxQc.png)

The resulting graph looks like this:

[Resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVP4A.png)

What do I need to do in order to change the sequence so that week 1 and 2 follow after week 52 on the x-axis?

Comment: I don't think there is a way ... you will need to create a separate column with years ... and order by years and after that by weeks

Comment: Ok, thanks for answering so quickly!

Comment: Is it me or is this very much so doable?